# Querying a selector that is inside a frame

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, dom-traversal

I am building a simple scraper with Puppeteer/JS.

I am trying to get an array of the paragraphs off a page and html is as seen in [this image][1].

When I use the id (`#iframeContent`), I get nothing. When I try to use a deep indicator, as such;

```
await page.$eval('#bookDesc_iframe_wrapper > iframe')
```

it loses track trying to hit > document or > #document.

When in the dev console on google, I can only find by query selector if I have gone and opened up that document > html > body manually, otherwise even google console doesn't see `#iframeContent`.

Comment: can you share the url in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use selectors across frames. You first have to find the frame and then work inside the frame. Use [`page.frames()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageframes) to get a list of all frames of the page and [`frame.name()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#framename) to identify your target frame.

You can then execute functions like [`frame.$$`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#frameselector-1) or [`frame.evaluate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#frameevaluatepagefunction-args) as you would on a page.

The code could look like this:

```js
const frames = await page.frames();
const iframe = frames.find(f => f.name() === 'bookDesc_iframe'); // name or id for the frame

const paragraphs = await iframe.$$('p');
```

Comment: Thank you much, had no idea about frames!